# Cards crops bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

Bootstrap cards inside card-columns block crops, how to disable it?

Here is screenshot.
http://piccy.info/view3/10286069/ca22a528ba433ab5b05119bb1d4e1fea/

```
<div class="card-columns">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">taras.shpachenko@yandex.ru</div>
    <div class="card-block">
      <p class="card-text">werewrwekek</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">taras.shpachenko@yandex.ru</div>
    <div class="card-block">
      <p class="card-text">werewrwekek</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">taras.shpachenko@yandex.ru</div>
    <div class="card-block">
      <p class="card-text">werewrwekek</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please include a jsfiddle or bootply link to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue introduced in alpha 4: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/20654

Looks like it will be fixed for alpha 5.

The workaround is to use..

```
.card-columns .card {
    display: inline-block;
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
.card-columns .card {
display: inline-block;
width:100%;}
```