# Bootstrap 4 Card cutting off div absolute content

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm having an issue where I'm trying to add a rounded icon to the top center of a card, but the part of the icon is cutting off. Need help figuring it out

```css
.header-icon-round {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    font-size: 30px;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: gray;
    border: 2px solid #dedede;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="card-columns">
        <div class="card card-block text-xs-center">
            <div class="header-icon-round">
                <i class="ti-wallet"></i>
            </div>
            <h4 class="card-title" style="padding-top: 80px;">
                My title
            </h4>
            <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur, inventore quod ab.</p>
            <a href="" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-rounded">Button Call</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I recently answered the same question here:
[Cards crops bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39531511/cards-crops-bootstrap-4)

This is a known issue introduced in alpha 4 (will be fixed in alpha 5): https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/20654

The workaround is to use..

```
.card-columns .card {
    display: inline-block;
    width:100%;
}
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/1V7ssBt8xq

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `position: absolute; top: -10px;` from `.header-icon-round` class.

```css
.header-icon-round {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    font-size: 30px;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: gray;
    border: 2px solid #dedede;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 60px;
    /*position: absolute;*/
/*     top: -10px;*/
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="card-columns">
        <div class="card card-block text-xs-center">
            <div class="header-icon-round">
                <i class="ti-wallet"></i>
            </div>
            <h4 class="card-title" style="padding-top: 80px;">
                My title
            </h4>
            <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur, inventore quod ab.</p>
            <a href="" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-rounded">Button Call</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for checking on this, but I want to have a part of the icon out a little bit of the card I don 't want it fully inside.

Comment: Well! remove `position: absolute;` only and use `top: -10px;` to move icon up/down as you want.

Comment: It doesn't work. Still cuts the top part of the circle (http://i64.tinypic.com/33osdqd.png). Also I notice that you used bootstrap 3 on the example you posted, but I'm using bootstrap 4.

Comment: Okey! what you want to make now?

Comment: You see it shows only half of the circle icon? I want the rest to show either, it should be showing a part outside the card. I don't want to move it down I want it on that position. Thanks!