# Bootstrap 4 masonry layout behaves differently in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

Im using bootstrap 4 [classes for masonry layout](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/#columns),
but I am getting varying results in firefox and chrome for mac.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class='card-columns'>
    <div class='card'>
      <h1>Something</h1>
    </div>
    <div class='card'>
      <h1>Something else</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can try this [reduced test case](http://codepen.io/glebez/pen/QKVokJ) in different browsers yourself. Basically, when there are a few items in the layout (in my case 2), in chrome they stack on top of each other in the same column, in ff they are distributed among columns.

Now i'm confused if this is a Bootstrap 4 problem, or actually different implementation of multicolumn layout in those browsers (BS uses column-count css property to make this layout).

Any guess on how can I achieve the same presentation in chrome as in ff, so the items are distributed among columns?

UPD. For anyone interested, here's a link to the issue on bootstrap repo, I've created following up this question: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/20925

Answer (score 2):

Being that Bootstrap 4 is still in alpha, you can expect some instability.

If you use the newer Bootstrap 4 alpha 4, you'll see the [stacking issue is resolved](http://www.codeply.com/go/lm6PzpCnOt). However, [alpha 4 introduces another issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39531511/cards-crops-bootstrap-4/39546895) (due to how CSS columns work) that makes the cards cropped.

Comment: The cropping is fixed by adding `display:inline-block;` to the card-columns div

Comment: If I use '.card-columns .card {display: inline-block;width:100%;}' the stacking issue in Chrome is back. I can't see that this issue is resolved. I am also looking for a solution that can be applied (manually) to Bootstrap3. Example: https://www.bootply.com/W5cQ4ECU00